# libreoffice calc prints everything landscape

Tags: printing, landscape-portrait, libreoffice-calc

I've got `Libreoffice Calc` per the following:

```
Version: 5.1.6.2
Build ID: 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial3
CPU Threads: 8; OS Version: Linux 4.13; UI Render: default; 
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); Calc: group
```

I select `FORMAT -> PAGE -> LANDSCAPE`.

Print preview looks normal (landscape), and the sheet prints *landscape*.

I select `FORMAT -> PAGE -> PORTRAIT`.

Print preview looks normal (*portrait*).

However, upon selecting actual `PRINT` command, the thumbnail image in the dialog shows the page in landscape orientation, with the print material half-size, and vertically oriented.

If I copy-paste the spreadsheet into a new workbook, this behavior is not replicated.

I suspect that there's some setting somewhere that I have inadvertently tripped, but now cannot find.

Anyone have an idea what it could be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was a bug that has been fixed.

I downloaded LibreOffice 6.0.3.2, and portrait printing now just works!